# I need a more mainstream replacement for the noun snark

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a replacement for the noun "snark". *Sarcasm* won't work because it's a form of humor and I want to add a suggestion of malice or darkness to it.

For example, as a response to a request to include a quote within [an answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/41848/12102) avoid a "link-only" situation, an author added the following to indicate passages that contained the word:

> 1: [...] horsepower [...]
>
> 2: [...] horsepower [...]
>
> 3: [...] horsepower [...]

By quoting only the single word from the passage rather than a sentence or so and repeating the same three times, the author pretends to expand beyond link-only but fails *by design.*

So while *pretense* comes to mind, it's also not dark enough. *Spite* is a bit strong. The idea here was to respond by following the letter of the request but not in spirit, perhaps to mock it.

Comment: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/snarky

Comment: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/snark/synonyms

Comment: This may say more about the people I hang out with: isn't **snark** mainstream?

Comment: Sarcasm is not always a form of humour.

Comment: Not sure how useful this is, but it feels closely related to being _disingenuous_.

Comment: @SteveLovell yes indeed it is! The example [cited there](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/disingenuous) is interesting: *this journalist was being somewhat disingenuous as well as cynical’* so perhaps *cynical [disingenuity](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/disingenuity)?*

Comment: If you're not looking for *sarcasm*, then the word you're looking for is not a synonym for *snark* (which *sarcasm* is), and you need to rephrase your question. ([*Snark*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/snark): "an attitude or expression of mocking irreverence and sarcasm.") For example, *snark* and *pretense* have nothing to do with each other—so if one comes to mind when you think of the other, you are not using one (or the other) correctly. *Spite*, similarly, is not synonymous with either. I suggest you look up the definitions of the various words you've used.

Comment: @JasonBassfordSupportsMonica I think your logic is less than inescapable. There is some flexibility in the meaning of snark, depending on context. The context that I describe above is the similar to that discussed in [If you really want to reduce the snark level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/138119/303080); shall we be just as zealous rooting out instances of sarcasm wherever we find it in SE, or is there a difference because sarcasm doesn't have quite the same "malice or darkness to it" as I propose in my first sentence?

Comment: I've updated the question and stricken the synonymization request.

Comment: *Snark* is as mainstream as it gets. The only word I can think of that's more mainstream is *beer*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt Merriam Webster lists it as "informal", the OED doesn't even include it (even as *US*) - except as "an imaginary animal".  It's a bit like "diaper", you rarely if ever hear it used in Britain, except by Americans - and when that happens I always wonder what it means.

Comment: @WS2 I'm neither a Brit nor an American, I have never visited either country, and English is not even my third language. It is with that in mind that I say that *snark* is about as obscure as *beer*.

Comment: @RegDwigнt In that case you must have been somewhere I've never been. However, I do know about the poem by Lewis Carroll -  [*The Hunting of the Snark*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hunting_of_the_Snark) But on further thoughts there is a slang form of "sarcastic" in Britain - ***sarky***. Perhaps it has something to do with that.

Comment: Prior to the internet, before there was *snark* there was *snide*. [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=snidely%2Csnark%2Csnarky%2Csnide&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csnidely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnark%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnarky%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnide%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csnidely%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnark%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnarky%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csnide%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @Mazura yes, good the good old snide comment. I wonder if we are actually being less snide and more snarky these days, or if it's only that one term is replacing another? Would a person skilled in the snidely arts transported here from the past have trouble producing proper 21st century snark? I think there's an SE question here somewhere...

Comment: I blame the internet (this site in particular actually) for making us have to use words that British people understand. *snide*, "North American :(of a person) devious and underhanded. British :counterfeit; inferior." - calling a comment snide in British would be, in itself, snide.

Comment: @Mazura I've always wondered about the naming of the character [Snidely Whiplash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snidely_Whiplash), you've given me new insight. The TV cartoon series was produced in the US, but the setting and characters were *Canadian*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> By quoting only the single word from the passage rather than a sentence or so and repeating the same three times, **the author pretends to expand beyond link-only but fails by design.**

The bolded text is often described as **malicious compliance**.

From Wikipedia's article on malicious compliance,

> Malicious compliance is the behaviour of intentionally inflicting harm by strictly following the orders of a superior knowing that compliance with the orders will not have the intended result. The term usually implies the following of an order in such a way that ignores the order's intent but follows it to the letter.[1]
>
> It is a specialized form of passive aggressive behavior. This is
>   sometimes called "work to rule" and encompasses the situation where
>   the subordinate sees both the folly of the order, rule, or direction
>   and the adverse results.[2]

Although ,in the example you described, suggesting the action was done to cause real harm is probably a stretch, it ticks enough of the boxes to work in my experience.